# Dynamically create an object based on a field

Tags: java, gson, android

I receive from a network API a JSON like this one:

```js
{
  ...
  "foobar":
    {
      "type": "...",
      "keyTypeA": "value"
    }
}
```

With `foobar` having different object types depending on its `type` field.
So, `foobar` can be:

```js
{
  "type": "typeA",
  "keyA1": "...",
  "keyA2": "...",
  ...
}
```

or

```js
{
  "type": "typeB",
  "keyB1": "...",
  "keyB2": "...",
  ...
}
```

etc.

How can I parse these JSON models into my POJO classes defined here:

```java
public class FoobarTypeBase {
    @SerializedName("type")
    public String type;
}

public class FoobarTypeA extends FoobarTypeBase {
    @SerializedName("keyA1")
    public SomeObject keyA1;
    @SerializedName("keyA2")
    public SomeObject keyA2;
}

public class FoobarTypeB extends FoobarTypeBase {
    @SerializedName("keyB1")
    public SomeObject keyB1;
    @SerializedName("keyB2")
    public SomeObject keyB2;
}
```

I guess I have to deal with `TypeAdapterFactory` and `TypeAdapter` but I don't known how to do it efficiently.

Comment: Try using GSON library. `new Gson()..fromJson(<your JSON here>,<Your class>);`

Comment: @Manindar This solution would force me to keep the raw JSON object for `foobar` in its parent object, and then to parse it. This would work, but it is not efficient nor elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use a combination of Retrofit + Gson and do it this way:

```
RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<FoobarTypeBase> itemFactory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
            .of(FoobarTypeBase.class, "type") // The field that defines the type
            .registerSubtype(FoobarTypeA.class, "foobar")
            .registerSubtype(FoobarTypeB.class) // if the flag equals the class name, you can skip the second parameter.

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(itemFactory)
            .create();
```

Then I initialize Retrofit like this:

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder();
    builder.baseUrl(BASE_URL);
    builder.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
```

Comment: RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory no longer exists in Gson official package.

Comment: I know. I actually include a personal implementation now. This is a real issue for me now, if you know a solution to it I'm still looking for one.